# How can I build a C program that embeds Lua?

Tags: c, gcc, lua

I'm trying to build a simple C program that embeds Lua.  On my iMac, it builds perfectly.  However, on my Macbook Pro it will not build.  I have a directory called `Lua5.2` in `/usr/local/include` that contains `lua.h`, `lauxlib.h` and `lualib.h`

When I try to build the program, I get the following linker error:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:sol David$ make
gcc sol.o -o sol -llua -lm
ld: library not found for -llua
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sol] Error 1
```

Here is the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CF = -c -Wall -I/usr/local/include/lua5.2

all: sol
  sudo mv sol /usr/bin
  rm -Rf *.o

sol: sol.o
  $(CC) sol.o -o sol -llua -lm

sol.o: sol.c
  $(CC) $(CF) sol.c -o sol.o
```

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: You need the appropriate `-L` option for the linker the way you needed the `-I` option for the compiler.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not very good with Makefiles.  Do you think you could show me an example?  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a makefile thing. This is a compiler/linker thing. You specified `-I` during so that the compiler could find the right header files. You need to do the same thing with `-L` for the path to the libraries for the linker.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still lost @EtanReisner.  Do you think you could edit what I posted and add it as an answer?

Comment: Find the lua library objects. Take that path. Add `-L<thatpath>` to the `$(CC) sol.o -o sol -llua -lm` line before the `-llua` argument.

Comment: How did you install the Lua library on your computer? If you used a package manager like Homebrew then it should have also installed either a static or dynamic version of the library and you can use `brew` to find it. If you installed it by manually copying those files to /usr/local/include then you may have to build the library on your own.

Comment: I used Homebrew to install it.  I uninstalled multiple times with `brew` and reinstalled, but I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @user3314993 Maybe the Lua library isn't called `liblua.a`. Try `-llua.5.2.4`. If that doesn't work, search for the installed Lua library using `find /usr/local/lib -name "liblua*"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with:

cc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o power.so -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -llua hellofunc.c

First I installed the brew gcc and rebuilt the links:

```
brew install gcc
brew unlink gcc
brew cleanup
brew link gcc
```

Then I made sure the right program was being called:

/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/bin/gcc-5 -Wall -shared -fPIC -o power.so -I/usr/local/include -llua hellofunc.c

This also solved the same error with: library not found for -lgfortran